# Send long SMS via RXTX and GSM Modem

Tags: java, rxtx

My Java Application sends SMS over a GSM Modem connected to COM port. For COM port communication I use RXTX. Everything works fine except sending long (concatenated) SMS.

The code for the port:

```
private final String        comPortID;

private SerialPort          serialPort;
private OutputStreamWriter  out;
private InputStreamReader   in;

public Port(String comPortID)
{
    this.comPortID = comPortID;
}

public void open() throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(comPortID);
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SMS Transceiver", 100);
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(19200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(serialPort.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
    in = new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("Port " + comPortID + " opened successfully");
}

public void write(String s) throws Exception
{
    out.write(s);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("Write to port: " + s);
}

public void write(char[] s) throws Exception
{
    out.write(s);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("Write to port: " + new String(s));
}

public void writeln(String s) throws Exception
{
    out.write(s);
    out.write('\r');
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("Write to port: " + s);
}

public String read() throws Exception
{
    final long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000;
    do
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } while (!in.ready() && System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout);

    final StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while (in.ready())
        {
            int n = in.read();
            if (n != -1)
            {
                char c = (char) n;
                answer.append(c);
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    System.out.println("Read from port: " + answer);
    return answer.toString();
}

public void close()
{
    try
    {
        serialPort.close();
        System.out.println("Port closed");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code for sending a long SMS:

```
        // Set message format to PDU mode  
        port.writeln("AT+CMGF=0");
        port.read();

        for (int i = 0; i < textParts.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\nSend SMS " + (i + 1) + " of " + textParts.size() + "\n");

            final byte[] pdu = PDUUtils.getPDUPart(dialno, textParts.get(i), DataCodingScheme.UCS2, i + 1, textParts.size());
            final char[] pduHex = PDUUtils.toHexString(pdu);

            port.writeln("AT+CMGS=" + pdu.length);
            port.read();

            port.write("00");
            port.write(pduHex);
            port.write("\u001A"); // Ctrl-Z
            port.read();
        }
```

The problem is not the creation of the PDU or AT commands. When I connect to the COM Port with PUTTY and send exactly the same commands to the modem the messages will be send correctly and will be received at my phone correctly as one SMS. So there must be a timing or configuration problem.

I get no error messages or exceptions. The information received by the read() method is always the same String I wrote via the write() methods before. Except the last read() of the last message (The long SMS is splitted into two parts). There I get different results. Mostly the String "AA" or "AAA" is returned and sometimes the String I wrote via the write() methods. In all cases the SMS is not received by my cell phone.

There is no general problem in sending SMS. When I send two not concatenated SMS (still in PDU mode) everthing works fine.

Can anybody help me please?